# Drupal 7 create custom template based on content type not working

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I want to create a custom template file based on the 'content type'. I have a content type named (machine name) : `oldperson_profile` and I have created a file under the "templates" folder as `page--oldperson_profile.php`. Now, based on the tutorials I found over Google, I did the following modifications in the template.php file:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables, $hook) {

 if (isset($variables['node']->type)) {
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__' . $variables['node']->type;
  }

}
```

Now I have cleared the cache and refresh the front end of the page, but nothing changed. I take the idea from https://www.digett.com/insights/overriding-page-templates-content-type-drupal-7 . Anything wrong I did?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your template file name is wrong, change underscore `_` to a dash '-' for your file name and also you are missing `tpl`
So it should be

```
page--oldperson-profile.tpl.php
```